# How to add a dependency that's packaged in a zip

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, dependencies, zip

I couldn't find how in gradle you were supposed to depend on a jar that is packaged in a zip dependency.
My use case is retrieving the platform-api.jar artifact from intellij's distribution repository.

Answer (score 1):

Searched everywhere but couldnt find an answer.
Solved it rather neatly by using a `zipTree` of a detached configuration of the distribution like so:

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation zipTree(project.configurations.detachedConfiguration(dependencies.create("com.jetbrains.intellij.idea:ideaIC:2021.1.2")).singleFile).matching {
        include "lib/platform-api.jar"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid unzipping each time the build runs you could use a task and make use of up-to-date checking (see [authoring tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html) and [declaring task inputs and outputs via the runtime api](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/incremental_build.html#sec:task_input_output_runtime_api))

```
configurations {
   intellij
}
dependencies {
   intellij 'com.jetbrains.intellij.idea:ideaIC:2021.1.2'
   implementation tasks.named('intellijUnzip')
}
tasks.register('intellijUnzip') {
   inputs.files configurations.intellij
   outputs.dir "$buildDir/intellijUnzip"
   doLast {
      copy {
         from zipTree(configurations.intellij.singleFile)
         include "lib/platform-api.jar"
         into "$buildDir/intellijUnzip"
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: The solution I have appears to be caching the unzipped jar in `.\build\tmp\.cache\expanded\zip_` so I believe it already avoids it.

On another note, is it documented anywhere that you could use task outputs as dependencies? I've searched everywhere and came up empty. Everything I did trying to make this into a task required me to run the task once and only on the next sync it would see the jar and add it. And it definitely isnt helping that task dependencies are also named "dependencies" so nothing shows up on google :/

Comment: All methods in the `dependencies { ... }` block are executed against the [DependencyHandler](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html). Those docs mention the different types of dependency notations including file dependencies. Possibly gradle need to update their [working with files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html) docs to include `tasks.named(...)` as an option

Comment: Ultimately, it's likely that [Project.files(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#files-java.lang.Object...-) is called on the argument. Notice how one of the options is a task